# Odoo : How to display html as menuitem's name?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

## Question :

In a menuitem such as :

```
<menuitem id="menu_id"
          name="menu name 3e"
          parent="parent_path"
          action="action_path"
          sequence="10"/>
```

How can I get the name to be equivalent to "`menu item 3<sup>e</sup>`" so it will be displayed like "menu item 3<sup>e</sup>"?

## Attempts :

**Code 1:**

```
<menuitem id="menu_id"
          name="menu name 3<sup>e</sup>"
          parent="parent_path"
          action="action_path"
          sequence="10"/>
```

Error:
`XMLSyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values, line 2, column 24`
*(line as been replaced in the error to be accurate in the snippet)*

**Code 2:**

```
<menuitem id="menu_id"
          name="menu name 3&lt;sup>e&lt;/sup>"
          parent="parent_path"
          action="action_path"
          sequence="10"/>
```

Error: No problem to upgrade module, but the name displayed is `menu name 3<sup>e</sup>`

*I also tried to escape using `\<` and `<<` instead of `<` but it is just desperate non-sense for xml*

## NB :

I have a similar question (not in-depth detailled here not to overload the question) about adding html in the value of a record's fields, or in a button text, for example `<field name="name">3<sup>e</sup></field>`

But it throws the error :
`AssertionError: Element field has extra content: sup, line 5`

No matter how I try to escape it, except for the replacement of `<` by `&lt;` but the result is the same as the 2sd attempts on the menuitem.

Comment: Nice question, if you got the answer please post it

Answer (score 0):

Why code 2 work for me: Odoo11

```
name="Projects 3&lt;sup> e&lt;/sup>"
```

[Let see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr4J2.png)

Comment: Your image show the unexpected behavior. It should be displayed as Projects 3<sup>e</sup>. I edited my question because the "error" I'm getting was not displayed as expected